# If each $B_N$ is finite, show that $A = \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} B_{N}$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis

\begin{equation}
    B_N = \{(a_{n}x^{n} +a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}x + a_{0}) :  \mid n \mid + \mid a_0 \mid + \mid a_1 \mid + ... + \mid a_n \mid = N\}
\end{equation}

I know that a countable union of finite sets is at most countable, and I know that each $B_N$ is finite for a fixed $N$. I'm not sure how to show that $A = \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} B_{N}$ is infinite to show that it must be countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact a stronger statement holds: the countably infinite union of countably infinite sets is countably infinite.  Let $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a family of sets, with each $A_k$ countably infinite. Let $\displaystyle{A = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k}$.

1. Let $P=\{2,3,5,7,11,13,\ldots\}$ be the set of prime numbers (recall there are infinitely many primes) and let $p_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ prime.  Consider the sets $\{I_{k}\}$ defined by setting $I_{0}=\{1\}$, $I_{1}=2\mathbb{N}^+=\{2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$, and letting $I_{k}$ be the set of positive integers divisible by $p_k$ but none of the preceding $p_j$s (with $1\leq j\leq k-1$). In symbols, for $k\geq 2$ define
   $$
       I_{k} = \left\{n\in\mathbb{N}^+ \,|\, p_k\text{ divides } n \right\}\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}I_{i} 
   $$
2. Each $I_{k} $ is distinct and infinite. Further, $\displaystyle{ \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}I_{k} =\mathbb{N^+}}$.
3. For each $k$, there is a bijection between $A_k$ and $I_{k} $. (This step requires the Axiom of Choice: close your eyes and do it.) Then $A$ and $\mathbb{N}^+$ are in bijection, hence $A$ is countable.